# What will Enable monero to scale where Bitcoin failed?

Tags: cryptocurrency-comparison, scalability

Bitcoin is failing below its own success and the inability of the core team to make it scales.

What are the main  resources explaining what differentiate Monero from bit coin regarding scalability of the network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Monero will scale where bitcoin failed because Monero is hardcoded to scale to the network infrastructure (a real variable), whereas Bitcoin is hardcoded to scale to a decision made by humans (the 1 MB block cap).